# Access element in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this dictionary which contains another dictionary inside:

```
dic = {'dos': {'int' : {'k' : ['float'], 'g': ['float']}}, 'uno': { 'int': {'k':['float']}}}
```

It stores the name of a function, its type and the parameters, MY problem is i cant access the type of the parameter, lets say for the function dos i want to get the int from the dictionary
I've tried with `dic['dos']` which will return `{'int' : {'k' : ['float'], 'g': ['float']}}` and also tried with `dic['dos'].itervalues.next()` which return `{'k' : ['float'], 'g': ['float']}`

Sorry if my explanation isn't clear enough, im fairly new to python and my knowledge of dictionaries and lists is limited

Comment: If possible I think it would be better if you knew the name of the `keys`, makes dictionaries much easier to work with.

Comment: Is `int` the return type of the function `dos`? Is the type of parameter `k` an array of `float`s?

Comment: This seems like a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why are your code structured like this?

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
print dic['dos'].keys()[0]  # Prints 'int'
```

but it's rather odd that you're using the key of a dictionary in this way.  Is it possible that this dictionary could have more than one entry?  I don't quite follow what your data structure is doing...

Comment: Thank you very much, since i just need to introduce the type of the function in that dictinary it doesnt really cause conflicts

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is only one key at that level

```
print next(iter(dic['dos']))
```

If there's more than one key, you can use

```
list(dic['dos'])  # returns a list in Python3 too
```